# Largest angle between three circle points

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, circles

> Given a circle $k$ with centre $M$ and another point $B$ inside the circle. Find those points $V$ on $k$ for which the angle $BVM$ has maximum size.

I think that the angle $MBV$ has to be $90°$ so that the other can have maximum size. Has anyone an idea for an approach?

Comment: @calculatormathematical There is a right angle involved, that much is true, but it's not $\angle BVM.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\textit{First solution:}$

There are exactly two such points, and they are those for which $|\angle M B V|=$ $90^{\circ}$ holds. This is how our problem looks in general for some point $B$:

[image: Figure 0]

We denote the radius of the given circle by $r$ and the centre of the line $\overline{B M}$ by $F$.

If the point $V$ lies on the straight line $B M$, $|\angle BVM|=0^{\circ}$ holds, and the angle is certainly not the largest possible. So we can additionally assume that the points $B$, $M$ and $V$ do not lie on a straight line, and then consider the circle $k^{\prime}$ with a radius $r^{\prime}$ through the points $B, M$ and $V$, cf. Figure $1$.

[image: Figure 1]

In this circle $\angle BVM$ is peripheral angle over the chord $\overline{B M}$. The centre $M^{\prime}$ of $k^{\prime}$ lies on the median perpendicular of $\overline{B M}$. According to the centroid-periphery angle theorem, $|\angle BVM|=\frac{1}{2}\left|\angle B M^{\prime} M\right|$, and $\left|\angle B M^{\prime} M\right|$ becomes greatest exactly, when $\left|M^{\prime} F\right|$ and hence the radius $r^{\prime}=\left|M^{\prime} M\right|$ of $k^{\prime}$ is smallest. According to the triangle inequality
$$
2 r^{\prime}=\left|M^{\prime} M\right|+\left|M^{\prime} V\right| \geq|M V|=r .
$$
Equality holds exactly when $M^{\prime}$ is a point of the line $\overline{M V}$.
We are thus looking for a situation with $r^{\prime}=r / 2$ where $M, M^{\prime}$ and $V$ lie on a common straight line. Since $k^{\prime}$ passes through the centre $M$ of the circle $k$, such a situation occurs exactly when the circle $k^{\prime}$ touches the circle $k$ from the inside, cf. figure $2$.

[image: Figure 2]

Due to Thales' theorem $|\angle M B V|=90^{\circ}$, which unambiguously determines the point $V$ with respect to the straight line $B M$ except for mirror symmetry.

---

$\textit{Second solution:}$

For every possible point $V$ obviously $|B M|<|M V|$ holds. Thus the angle $\angle B V M$ in the (possibly degenerate) triangle $B M V$ is not opposite the largest side, and $0^{\circ} \leq|\angle B V M|<90^{\circ}$. Thus $|\angle B V M|$ becomes maximal exactly when $\sin |\angle B V M|$ is maximal.
According to the sine theorem in the (possibly degenerate) triangle $B M V$.
$$
\frac{\sin |\angle B V M|}{|B M|}=\frac{\sin |\angle M B V|}{|M V|}
$$
Since $|B M|$ and, because of the position of $V$ on $k$, also $|M V|$ are constant, the two sine values differ only by a constant positive factor. Thus $\sin |\angle B V M|$ becomes maximum exactly when $\sin |\angle M B V|$ also becomes maximum. This occurs exactly when $\angle M B V|=90^{\circ}$.
So there are exactly two points $V$ with the property we are looking for, namely those for which $|\angle M B V|=90^{\circ}$ holds.

---

$\textit{Third solution:}$

We introduce Cartesian coordinates. Let $M=(0,0), B=(b, 0)$, and let $k$ be the unit circle without restriction of generality. Then $V=(\cos \varphi, \sin \varphi)$ with some $\varphi$. The point $P$ lies exactly inside the circle if $|b|<1$.
The following are now valid, firstly
$$
\overrightarrow{M V} \cdot \overrightarrow{B V}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\cos \varphi \\
\sin \varphi
\end{array}\right) \cdot\left(\begin{array}{c}
\cos \varphi-b \\
\sin \varphi
\end{array}\right)=\cos ^{2} \varphi-b \cos \varphi+\sin ^{2} \varphi=1-b \cos \varphi
$$
then
$$
|\overrightarrow{V M}|=1
$$
as well as
$$
|\overrightarrow{V B}|=\sqrt{(\cos \varphi-b)^{2}+\sin ^{2} \varphi}=\sqrt{1+b^{2}-2 b \cos \varphi} 
$$
and thus
$$
\cos |\angle B V M|=\frac{1-b \cos \varphi}{\sqrt{1+b^{2}-2 b \cos \varphi}} .
$$
Because of $|b|<1$ and $|\cos \varphi| \leq 1$ this value is positive, so $\angle B V M$ is an acute angle. Pointed angles are largest when their sine becomes maximum.
Using the binomial formula $(1-b \cos \varphi)^{2}=1+b^{2} \cos ^{2} \varphi-2 b \cos \varphi$ gives
$$
\sin |\angle B V M|=\sqrt{1-\cos ^{2}|\angle B V M|}=\sqrt{\frac{b^{2}-b^{2} \cos ^{2} \varphi}{1+b^{2}-2 b \cos \varphi}}=|b| \sqrt{\frac{\sin ^{2} \varphi}{\sin ^{2} \varphi+(\cos \varphi-b)^{2}}}
$$
The term on the right side now takes its maximum $|b|$ exactly when $\cos \varphi=b$ holds, i.e. the point $V$ has the same abscissa $b$ as the point $B$.
This applies to exactly two points of the unit circle for which $|\angle M B V|=90^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take any $V$, then construct points $V_1$ and $V_2$ on $k$ such that $V_1$ lies on continuation of $VB$ and $V_2$ lies on continuation of $VM$. Then $\angle BVM=\angle V_1VV_2=\frac{\angle V_1MV_2}{2}\leq 90°$.

**But** If $\angle BVM=90°$, then $\angle V_1MV_2=180°$ then $V_1V_2$  is diameter. $VV_2$ is also diameter. Then $V$ is the same as $V_1$ which is contradictory. So angle $90°$ cannot be obtained.

Let's consider point $U$ which is center of circumscribed circle of triangle $BVM$. Then $\angle BVM=\frac{\angle BUM}{2}$. Let $D$ is middle of $BM$, then $\angle BUM=2\angle BUD$, $\angle BVM=\angle BUD$. Point $U$ is such that $BU=MU=VU$. Using triangle rule, we can say that $2 BU = MU+VU \geq MV = R$, then $BU \geq \frac{R}{2}$. Then $\sin BVM=\sin BUD=\frac{BD}{BU}=\frac{BM/2}{BU} \leq \frac{BM}{R}$. As $BVM \leq 90°$, maximum sine corresponds to maximum value of angle. Then $\angle BVM \leq \arcsin \frac{BM}{R}$. Note that maximum angle value corresponds to $MU=BU=\frac{R}{2}$ and $MU+VU=MV$.

To find point $V$, one need to construct $U$ which is intersection of circle with radius $MU=\frac{R}{2}$ and perpendicular bisector of $BM$ where $BU=MU$. Then point of intersection of $MU$ continuation with $k$ will be $V$. There are two possible location of this point symmetric about $BM$ line.